# Quick Sort in C Issue

Tags: c, quicksort

I'm been stuck at a certain point in my quick sort program in C. Can anybody point out where the error is? My code doesn't run and I've tried comparing it with multiple online programs. I've got a test tomorrow and I want to know what the error is before I attempt it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int a,int b){
    int t;
    t=a;
    a=b;
    b=t;
}

int partition(int a[],int l,int h){
    int pi=l,i=l,j=h;
    while(i<j){
            while(a[i]<=a[pi])
                i++;
            while(a[j]>a[pi])
                j--;
            if(i<j){
                swap(a[i],a[j]);
            }
        }
    swap(a[j],a[pi]);
    return j;
}

void quicksort(int a[],int l,int h){
    int j;
    j=partition(a,l,h);
    quicksort(a,l,j-1);
    quicksort(a,j+1,h);
}

int main(){
    int n,i;
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    printf("Enter the elements: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    quicksort(a,0,n-1);
    printf("The array after sorting is: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your swap will swap only the local variables `a` and `b`. It will not affect the array `a` in the function `partition`.

Comment: I dont understand you, can you suggest a correction?

Comment: What @MOehm is trying to say is `void swap(int* a_ptr, int* b_ptr) ...` should give you a hint.

Comment: An alternative to Bo R's suggestion is to use `void swap(int array[], int i, int j)` to swap elements in an array.

Comment: Im trying to do it without using pointers, can you finish the swap function without pointers completely? I'm sorry, I'm unable to properly comprehend how to finish that.

Comment: There are other problems. For example you don't stop the recursion when the subarrays have only on element.

Comment: I also dont understand why it wouldnt affect the array in the partition function, because I'm treating the indices of the array as variables to be swapped arent I? Why doesnt the swap of their values happen?

Comment: You ran into the issue of parameters being passed by value vs. being passed by reference, which is a very fundamental thing to programming (not just C language). Please read a textbook about it and make sure you really understand the difference.

Comment: Alright, thank you for mentioning that. I will go through that thoroughly again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several issues.

First, your swap function swaps the local variables `a` and `b`, but it won't affect the array `a` in `partition`. Ian Abbott has explained this more thoroughly.

One way to solve that is to pass the addresses of the array elements via pointers, so that `swap` can access and change them. A simpler way is to write a swap function that operates on indices of an array:

```
void swap(int array[], int i, int j)
{
    int t = array[i]; array[i] = array[j]; array[j] = t;
}
```

Second, must stop the recursion at some time. When you have an array with only one element or with no elements at all, there's nothing to do, because the array (or subarray) is already sorted.

So don't do anything in that case. Or, rather, only do something when you have at least two elements. That has the nice side effect that the recusrion actually stops. `:)`

```
void quicksort(int a[], int l, int h)
{
    if (l < h) {
        int j;

        j = partition(a, l, h);
        quicksort(a, l, j - 1);
        quicksort(a, j + 1, h);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay yes thank you, the code works now, I'm trying to learn through implementation and am probably making too many mistakes but I appreciate the learning. Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me properly.

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments are *passed by value* in C. Your `swap` function:

```
void swap(int a,int b){
    int t;
    t=a;
    a=b;
    b=t;
}
```

gets passed two integer arguments, `int a` and `int b`. Within the function, they behave like local variables, so changes to `a` and `b` within the `swap` function have *no effect* on the caller.

To mimic the effect of *passing by reference*, you can use pointers to pass the addresses of the objects whose values are to be modified, and *dereference* the pointers inside the function to access the objects that are to be modified.

For example, your `swap` function can be modified as follows:

```
void swap(int *a,int *b){
    int t;
    t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

The calls to this function also need to be modified to pass the addresses of the objects whose values are to be swapped. For example, `swap(a[i],a[j]);` needs to be changed to `swap(&a[i],&a[j]);` (or equivalently, changed to `swap(a+i,a+j);`).

Comment: Thank you for the correction Ian, but my code gives me the same issue even after I used your suggestions.

Comment: I seem to have not fixed the recursion issue, which is why it didnt work. I did understand the passing by value though, thank you for taking the time to explain to me.